# Automatically reloading configuration

Tags: go

I am trying to implement Auto Reload configurations whenever a change to the config parameter is done after the modules are up.

How I am doing is I have set the triggers for the particular table where the configurations are maintained so whenever insert/update/delete performed, I am maintaining another table to keep track of the changes, so whenever the change is performed I am updating the counter and the current time in the second table for that particular row.

ex:

```
my 2nd Table schema(Tracker table):
tablename|counter|time
configtab, 2, 0001-01-01 00:00:00(just showing dummy values)
```

So for every update to configtab I will be updating the counter in my second table i.e Tracker table.

In my Go code, I have written 2 methods:
Method 1: which returns the counter and time values
Method 2: which compares the values passed counter and time with the values present in DB
if matched returns false(No changes) and returns true saying the configs were modified

The configurations were loaded into a MAP-> key-> string ,val->slice of strings, and accessed inside various packages

example, I have some LOG configurations there also I am initiating values by fetching from the map.
so if the configurations were changed I am updating the map which I am maintaining, But I am not getting how to send signals to those packages which were using that map to reassign the configuration again

Answer (score 0):

This all seems rather complicated. Can you keep the config in memory? If so just do this:

- Config is one map in memory with a mutex
- Call sites always ask for config values on every use

As it is in-memory it is fast, as there is one copy it is always up to date, as you always call for fresh values before use you don't need to tell consumers if it changes. The only good reason not to use in memory is if it is shared across processes.
Be aware though that your config is essentially a set of global variables so you should limit its use to things which need to be changed by users after build time, keep stuff which only programmers change as constants in packages.